# What are the advantages of using a European Amazon SES service?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I run a EU-based website on Amazon EC2, and currently send around 13,000 emails a day through Amazon SES. Much of the email throughput is during the early hours of the morning.

Now that Amazon SES has instances in Europe, are there any advantages to me switching from the current US-west SES servers into Europe? Does it make any difference in terms of deliverability or anything else?

The only benefit I can really see is one of slight speed increase; but email sending is done away from anything user-facing anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using your in-region SES, you won't be paying outbound bandwidth charges.

Other than that, I can't think of any other tangible benefits.

Comment: Hadn't considered that. That is possibly worth a change by itself.

Comment: ...further... My data transfer bill was $5.90 last month; including raw HTML pages from the webserver (which I assume is most of it). So, I don't need to worry about it; though I should set up new projects to use it, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

> Now that Amazon SES has instances in Europe, are there any advantages to me switching from 
>   the current US-west SES servers into Europe?

For you? No. Unless the website part is significant - then, obviously, people from europe have a lower latency.

This may be different if you run a game server or another latency problematic application. Websites normally are not so much, and email is not at all.

Comment: My EC2 instances are in Europe, in fact. Just that my SES is in US-West.